# How to remove a line break from a string

Tags: c

I have a text file with the following characters shown below

```
An investment
in knowledge 
pays the 
best interest
```

My code my code is supposed to read the the file and print it out in one line as shown below

```
An investment in knowledge pays the best interest
```

My code is below;

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\abiye\\Downloads\\abiye.txt", "r");

    char c;
    int d = 0;
    char arr[200];

    do
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c",c);
        d = d + 1;
        if (c == '\n') {
            putchar(' ');

        }


        arr[d] = c;

    }
    while (c != EOF);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    }
```

But instead of giving me the desired result I get the following printed

```
An investment 
in knowledge(A space is added at the beginning of this string and the rest that follow)
pays the 
best interest
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user3121023: But the Standard IO library is forced to translate that into a single `'\n'`.

Comment: BTW, if you don't what to get into serious problems, get rid out of `char arr[200];` and corresponding `arr[d] = c;` once and for great good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are printing the character before you check.

What you want to do is to check and then print.

```
do
{
    c = fgetc(fp);
    d += 1;
    if (c == '\n') {
        putchar(' ');
    }
    else
        putchar(c);
    arr[d] = c;
}
while (c != EOF);
```

Comment: Perhaps also handle `\r` and `\f` and `\t`